# Azure AD B2C Forgot Password - Disable Continue until Verification Complete

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We are using Custom Policies for our flows and finishing up the “Forgot Password” functionality. It works, but is turning out to be a little user unfriendly and causing confusion.

When a user goes to reset there password, they are sent a verification code to there email. After receiving the code, a handful of users are clicking “Continue” instead of “Verify” first and then an error is shown. They just assume something went wrong and do not notice or think to click “Verify” instead.

Is there any way to disable “Continue” until the verify is completed? Or even just bypass continue all together and if verify is successful…go to next screen?

Comment: hi @jonathan-mabrito did you get any solution for this one, i am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Javascript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) i.e. something similar to [this](https://github.com/stevenxzhou-zz/B2C-Samples/blob/master/Email-Verification-Automatic-Redirect.js).

```
// Make sure always remove the continue button if it exists.
    if (continueBtn) {
        continueBtn.remove();
    }
```